# How to specify a map within hugo content front matter

Tags: hugo, toml

In my hugo content files i want to define various images with their respective alts within the front matter. I want to be able to query that field using `.Params.images`

Represented as json `images` should look similar to this:

```
{ "images" : [
     {
      "src" : "images/giraffe.png",
      "alt" : "giraffe"
     },
     {
      "src" : "/images/elephant.png",
      "alt" : "elephant"
     },
     ...
   ]
}
```

How can i specify that within my front matter?

Answer (score 0):

TOML:

```
[[images]]
src = "images/giraffe.png"
alt = "giraffe"

[[images]]
src = "/images/elephant.png"
alt = "elephant"
```

YAML:

```
images:
- src: "images/giraffe.png"
  alt: "giraffe"
- src: "/images/elephant.png"
  alt: "elephant"
```

For more complex structures, see:

- this [snippet of code in the Hugo documentation](https://gohugo.io/content-management/front-matter/#target-specific-pages)
- [TOML Front-Matter specs](https://%20https://toml.io/en/)
- [YAML Front-Matter specs](https://yaml.org/spec/)